# Windows installer failing with error "Error writing to file: System.Web.Extensions.dll. Verify that you have access to that directory."

Tags: windows-installer, gac

I have a simple windows installer package that I created. All it does is install 2 .dll's into the GAC. This is a production machine, so as I understand it, it is a best practice to install to the GAC in this way (as opposed to using gacutil.exe, etc.)

This installer works fine on another server that I have for testing. The server it works on, however, is just a plain vanilla installation of Win2k3, with nothing else installed. The production server this installer is failing on is a Win2k3 box with service packs, and a load of other software on it.

I am not sure how to go about troubleshooting this. There are no events thrown in the even logs, etc. No indication of what is wrong. [This question on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/c13c32d0-aaca-4547-a2cf-2d04ad13ef9a) has some hints, but I can't seem to find any real answers.

[image]

Comment: Come on folks, don't let this one become a tumbleweed!!!

Comment: Can you post a link to the full installation log so we can take a look?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my guess without looking at any logfile:

1) You shouldn't even be installing this assembly as it's part of .NET 3.5.  You also probably didn't tell your installer to install it.  It's just one of those wonderful feature that makes Visual Studio Deployment projects, well, "special"   It likes to detect dependencies and then it's up to you to "exclude" them ( right click | exclude )

2) The machine that it's "working" probably has .NET 3.5 and since that version of the assembly is already in the GAC, MSI simply skips it.

3) The machine that is not working ( you said it's W2K3 with nothing else ) probably only has .NET 1.1 ( it came preinstalled ) and when MSI tries to install a .NET 3.5 assembly ( CLR 2.0 ) it doesn't have a clue how to do this so a throws a (misleading) error.

Again, just a guess since you didn't provide a [windows installer log](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300).

And finally one more possible lead:

[MSI: "Error writing to file: ******.dll. Verify that you have access to that directory. GAC problem?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/c13c32d0-aaca-4547-a2cf-2d04ad13ef9a)

Regardless I suspect my hunch is correct that you should just exclude the assembly as it's already laid down by .NET 3.5.

PS- Installers are a niche space so 14hours isn't really tumbleweed time like it might be in C# where 500 people try to answer a question in 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks Christopher. I will work on getting the windows installer log working so I can check this out. The machine it is working on only has .NET 2.0. It installed as a required prerequisite of using the installer. The production machine I am _trying_ to install it on only has .net 2.0 as well. I thought I _had_ excluded extra dependencies, but I will look again. I will come back with more info, based on your answer here. Thanks foe the help so far!!!  :-)